# PHP - check if range appears in variable?

Tags: php, range, match

I have a variable like this :

```
$test = "002,003,004,005,012,032,045";
```

I'd like to see if any number in a range of numbers appears in this string.

eg : `if ($test == [010-015]) echo "found";`

this would check the $test variable for any number of 010,011,012,013,014,015 and if any is found then echo found.

How do I do this ?

Only way I can think of is to loop through each number .. but there must be a better way !

Thanks

Comment: [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array_intersect) would work, after splitting up the list, and using a [`range()`](http://php.net/range) for the comparison.

Comment: `if (!empty(array_intersect(explode(',', $test), range(10,15))))`

Comment: if $test is a string, and there is absolutely no formatting, then you will have O(n) anyway. However, if your string is sorted, has values between 0 and 999, and are always 3 digits then you can straight up do a binary search on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hope this helps you

```
$test = "002,003,004,005,012,032,045";
foreach (explode(',',$test) as $i)
{
  if($i > 10 && $i < 15)
  {
    echo 'found';
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks this seems to work. Any way to turn it into a function so I can pass 2 three digit number to it and check.  ie: 010-015, 037-042 etc. Thinking about this, I'd need to pass the 2 three digit numbers and the wording I want it to echo as it will change based on the number range.

Comment: `function test($l, $h, $sec, $test) {
foreach (explode(',',$test) as $i) {
 if($i > $l && $i < $h) echo $sec;
 }
}

test ("010","015", "Found", $test);` This seems to work !

Comment: the above doesn't work. well it does but if there are two matches in the range then I 2 two echos of Found. 3 match three found. Any way around that ?

Comment: put `break;` after echo